# How to split multi-voice lilypond scores to multiple midi outputs (e.g. for choir practice)

Tags: midi, lilypond

After spending long enough learning lilypond and writing scores for multiple voices, I've often run into the problem of generating individual voice midi/mp3 files from the score. I was surprised to find this was not already a feature or that no one had an easy way to do this since individual voice mp3s are a precious resource for learning a multi-voice piece !

While it is possible to just remove other voices from the score temporarily, compile, rename the midi, change to another voice, compile, rename, etc.. This becomes very tedious very fast.
Plus, I find it helpful to still have the other voices at low volume in the background to have a sense of the harmony.

So I need a way to generate these separate voices from a standard multi-voice score.

Here is a standard lilypond script for a 4-voice example to use as a test file :

```
\version "2.18.2"

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
  \tempo "Allegro" 2 = 60
}

% Lyrics
verseBass = \lyricmode {Ho Ho Hoo, Ho Ho Hoo !
}
verseTenor = \lyricmode {Ha Ha Haa, Ha Ha Haa !
}
verseAlto = \lyricmode {Huu Hu Hu, Hu Hu Huu !
}
verseSoprano = \lyricmode {Hi Hi Hii, Hi Hi Hii !
}

% Music
voiceBass = \relative c {\global c4 b f'2 d4 g, c2 \bar "|."}
voiceTenor = \relative c' {\global g4 b c2 b4 f g2}
voiceAlto = \relative c' {\global e2 d4 g g b, e2}
voiceSoprano = \relative c'' {\global c8e d4 a2 d4 b c2}

% Score stucture
voicePartBass = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Bass"
  shortInstrumentName = "B"
  midiInstrument = "violin" 
} {
  
  \clef bass \voiceBass   
} \addlyrics { \verseBass }

voicePartTenor = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Tenor"
  shortInstrumentName = "T"
  midiInstrument =  "violin" 
} { 
  
  \clef "G_8" \voiceTenor
} \addlyrics {\verseTenor}

voicePartAlto = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Alto"
  shortInstrumentName = "A"
  midiInstrument = "violin" 
} {
  
  \voiceAlto   
} \addlyrics { \verseAlto }

voicePartSoprano = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Soprano"
  shortInstrumentName = "S"
  midiInstrument =  "violin" 
} { 
  
  \voiceSoprano
} \addlyrics {\verseSoprano}


\score {
    <<
      \new ChoirStaff << % choirstaff adds the fancy join on voice staves
        \voicePartSoprano
        \voicePartAlto
        \voicePartTenor 
        \voicePartBass
      >>
    >>
    \layout {}
    \midi {}
}
```

Which outputs

[image]

And a midi file with everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR : You add some tags and there's a bash script at the end which automates the separate midi part generation (for Unix users only, sorry :P)

#### The `midiMaximumVolume` option

In my quest for a multi-voice split, I found out about [an option called
`midiMaximumVolume`](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/controlling-midi-dynamics#setting-midi-volume) which can be set within a `Staff` environment.
By setting this variable to a value between 0 and 1, it's possible to tone down (or entirely suppress) the volume of the staff it's placed within.

This needs to be set for each voice, so it's about as tedious as removing the music variables of other parts and then you still have to do the compiling/renaming shenanigans.

However it's already a great step towards automation of split-voices since it is a single parameter that can be targeted (instead of any custom `\myvoice` variables one may use...)

Plus, this makes it possible to have the other voices at a low volume in the background by setting them to a lower volume (eg. main voice at 1, others at 0.3).

#### Introducing a tag system

So the idea is to tag each part in its staff with a name & tag so we can easily detect where to introduce the volume parameter as well as a name for each part (mainly for file-naming). I went with something like this :

```
%#%part:<part_name>
```

Which fits in a lilypond comment. It must be placed at the location where the volume option would be set. Using the example above, it would be like so :

```
% Score stucture
voicePartBass = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Bass"
  shortInstrumentName = "B"
  midiInstrument = "violin" 
} {
  %#%part:Bass
  \clef bass \voiceBass   
} \addlyrics { \verseBass }

voicePartTenor = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Tenor"
  shortInstrumentName = "T"
  midiInstrument =  "violin" 
} { 
  %#%part:Tenor
  \clef "G_8" \voiceTenor
} \addlyrics {\verseTenor}
```

#### Bash magic

Now we have to target each tag and change it into the appropriate commands to use its voice as the main voice with the others in background, and repeat for all tags.

I made this into a bash function `ly2partmidi` (at the end of the post).

You can now source the function and run

```
$ ly2partmidi test.ly
```

which generates `test_<part_name1>.midi`, `test_<part_name2>.midi`, etc. in one go !

To modulate the volume (or silence) voices :

```
$ ly2partmidi <file.ly> <mainvolume> <othervolume>
```

eg. to remove other voices completely `ly2partmidi <file.ly> 1 0` or to have all but the main voice `0 1`, default is `1 0.3`.

If we set up the `test.ly` file above properly, and run the function, it generates `test_Soprano.midi`, `test_Alto.midi`, `test_Tenor.midi` and `test_Bass.midi` files, as expected.

You can also add a midi2mp3 step in there, if you want.

The bash function :

```
ly2partmidi () {
    lyfile=${1}
    volumeMain=${2:-1} # level of the 'main' voice of a file
    volumeOther=${3:-0.3} # level of the other voices (set to 0 if completely silent)
    tagregex="^\s*%#%part:([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)"
    setvolcmd="\\\set midiMaximumVolume = #"
    
    # find the tags in the .ly file
    mapfile -t fulltags < <(  grep -Po ${tagregex} ${lyfile} )
    tagnames=()
    
    for t in ${fulltags[@]} ; do
        t1=$(echo $t | sed -E "s/${tagregex}/\1/")
        tagnames+=("$t1") 
    done
    
    # get unique of each tag
    fulltags=($(echo "${fulltags[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))
    tagnames=($(echo "${tagnames[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))
    
    # for each tag...
    for i in ${!fulltags[@]}; do
        ft=${fulltags[$i]}
        t=${tagnames[$i]}
        
        echo -e "\n--- Generating part [$t] ..."
        echo -e "\tCopying lilypond script"
        # make temp copy of .ly
        t_lyfile=${lyfile/.ly/_$t.ly}
        cp -f $lyfile $t_lyfile
        
        echo -e "\tReplacing tags with midiVolume cmd"
        # replace tags with the midiVolume cmds
        sed -i -E "s/${ft}/${setvolcmd}${volumeMain}/g" $t_lyfile
        sed -i -E "s/${tagregex}/${setvolcmd}${volumeOther}/g" $t_lyfile
        
        echo -e "\tRunning lilypond engraving to generate midi"
        # generate midi
        lily_o=${t_lyfile/.ly/}
        lilypond -s -dno-print-pages -o $lily_o $t_lyfile
        
        rm $t_lyfile
        
    done
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your solution obviously works, but you *don't* need any compile/rename/rinse/repeat shenanigans.

You can put multiple `\score` blocks in one file. Each of those blocks will typeset the music into some file if it has the `\layout` block inside of it, and it will put MIDI into some file if it has the `\midi` block inside of it. So you can add another score block that would look along these lines:

```
\score {
    \new Staff \with {
        midiInstrument = "saxophone"
        midiMinimumVolume = #1
        midiMaximumVolume = #1
    } \new Voice \soprano
    \new Staff \with {
        midiInstrument = "acoustic grand"
        midiMinimumVolume = #0.4
        midiMaximumVolume = #0.4
    } \new Voice \alto
    % etc for \tenor and \bass
    % NO \layout block!!
    \midi {}
}
```

This will make a file `your-filename-0.midi` with your soprano played by a loud saxophone and the other parts by a quiet piano. You didn't put a `\layout` block in it, so it will typeset no music, just make the MIDI. Rinse & repeat for the other three voices.

Of course you can further automate this. I use this function (which I pilfered somewhere years ago, I don't remember where):

```
rehearsalMidi = #
(define-music-function
 (parser location name midiInstrument lyrics) (string? string? ly:music?)
 #{
     \unfoldRepeats <<
         \new Staff = "sopran" \new Voice = "sopran" { s1*0\f \sopran }
         \new Staff = "alt" \new Voice = "alt" { s1*0\f \alt }
         \new Staff = "tenor" \new Voice = "tenor" { s1*0\f \tenor }
         \new Staff = "bas" \new Voice = "bas" { s1*0\f \bas }
         \context Staff = $name {
             \set Score.midiMinimumVolume = #0.5
             \set Score.midiMaximumVolume = #0.5
             \set Score.tempoWholesPerMinute = #(ly:make-moment 100 4)
             \set Staff.midiMinimumVolume = #1.0
             \set Staff.midiMaximumVolume = #1.0
             \set Staff.midiInstrument = $midiInstrument
         }
         \new Lyrics \with {
             alignBelowContext = $name
         } \lyricsto $name $lyrics
     >>
 #})
```

Now I just add blocks like this,

```
\book {
    \bookOutputSuffix "sopran"
    \score {
        \rehearsalMidi "sopran" "soprano sax" \slovaI
        \midi { }
    }
}
```

one for each voice. The three arguments to `\rehearsalMidi` are: the voice whose part it is, the instrument that part should be played on, and the lyrics to go with that. Since we call the four voices *soprán*, *alt*, *tenor* and *bas* in Czech, I use these names for my voices, but you will surely be able to tinker with the function to make it meet your needs. The `book` and `bookOutputSuffix` just make the file names nicer, e. g. `my-filename-sopran.midi`, `my-filename-alt.midi` etc. instead of `my-filename-0.midi` etc.

By the way, when you write this one time, you can copy&paste it into all of the choral music you typeset (which is what I'm doing several years already :)).

Comment: Wow, that's a very good approach as well ! I'm not experienced enough in lilypond's language to make functions like yours, so I went with an 'outside' approach to automation and keep lilypond only for the music.

Comment: I have a question on your function, though : If it does not typeset any music, what's the point of having the lyrics added ?

Comment: @RoB, the function is just a "source code generator", it just writes a larger block of source code. Nothing complicated. // The lyrics get embedded into the MIDI somehow. I guess that some programs can then make advantage of it (esp. programs that "convert" MIDI back to score).

Answer (score 0):

[Nancho Alvarez](https://www.uma.es/victoria/nancho/index.html), LilyPond typesetter of Tomás Luis de Victoria's scores ([Partituras de Tomás Luis de Victoria](https://www.uma.es/victoria/partituras.html)), wrote a C program that splits MIDI tracks into separate MIDI files: [**splitmidi.c**](https://www.uma.es/victoria/scripts/splitmidi.c).

Answer (score 0):

As interesting as these answers are, there’s a good case for a low-code solution that doesn’t require external Bash scripts, C programs, or defining new functions. It uses two basic functions built into LilyPond: output file names (https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/output-file-names) and includes (https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/including-lilypond-files).

Consider the following directory hierarchy:

```
┌─ base
├─┬─ music
│ └─── example.ily
│
├─┬─ score
│ └─┬─ audio.ily
│   ├─ example.ily
│   └─ printed.ily
│
├─┬─ words
│ └─── example.ily
│
└─── compile.ly
```

The contents of your base folder are just three directories (`music`, `words`, `score`) and one compile file (`compile.ly`).

Inside your `music` and `words` folders are simply the `.ily` files containing, respectively, your music and words variables.

Inside your `score` folder is one `.ily` file that uses two `\include` statements to reference two other `.ily` files:

1. a `\book` and `\score` block that only results in printed music (`printed.ily`)
2. several `\book` and `\score` blocks that only result in audio files (`audio.ily`)

How does it look?

`compile.ly`

```
\version "2.22.0"
\include "./music/example.ily"
\include "./words/example.ily"
\include "./score/example.ily"
```

`music/example.ily`

```
sop = \relative c' {
  c4 d e f
  e d e2
}
alt = \relative c' {
  e4 f g a
  g fis g2
}
ten = \relative c' {
  c2 b
  a g
}
bas = \relative c {
  a2 e'
  a, a
}
```

`words/example.ily`

```
sop_words = \lyricmode {
  so -- pra -- no
  words they are here
}
alt_words = \lyricmode {
  al -- to words be
  here yo ho
}
ten_words = \lyricmode {
  ten -- or
  words -- ies
}
bas_words = \lyricmode {
  gol -- lum
  gol -- lum
}
```

`score/example.ily`

```
\include "./printed.ily"
\include "./audio.ily"
```

`score/printed.ily`

```
\book {
  \bookOutputName "my_printed_score"
  \score {
    <<
      \new ChoirStaff <<
        \new Voice = "sop" \sop
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto sop \sop_words
        \new Voice = "alt" \alt
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto alt \alt_words
        \new Voice = "ten" { \clef "treble_8" \ten }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto ten \ten_words
        \new Voice = "bas" { \clef bass \bas }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto bas \bas_words
      >>
    >>
    \layout {}
  }
}
```

`score/audio.ily`

```
\book {
  \bookOutputName "midi_sop"
  \score {
    \new Staff \sop
    \midi {}
  }
}
\book {
  \bookOutputName "midi_alt"
  \score {
    \new Staff \alt
    \midi {}
  }
}
\book {
  \bookOutputName "midi_ten"
  \score {
    \new Staff \ten
    \midi {}
  }
}
\book {
  \bookOutputName "midi_bas"
  \score {
    \new Staff \bas
    \midi {}
  }
}
```

As I said above, the two functions that make the difference here are `bookOutputName` and `include`.

Using `bookOutputName`, you’re able to produce multiple files—in this case, one that will only have the soprano music, another with only the alto music, etc. Of course, if you desire, you can add other instruments and control how loud they are and their stereo positions (left ear / right ear), among other options:

```
\book {
  \bookOutputName "midi_sop_bas"
  \score {
   <<
    \new Staff \with {
      midiMinimumVolume = #0.8
      midiPanPosition = #-1
    } \sop
    \new Staff \with {
      midiMaximumVolume = #0.5
      midiPanPosition = #1
    } \bas
   >>
    \midi {}
  }
}
```

(The reason for bringing up `\include` is to comment out `%` the `\include "./printed.ily"` file when you are fine with how the music looks and only want to tweak the way it sounds. Compiling MIDI alone with no layout block is often orders of magnitude faster.)

In this case, all you would need to do now is put a few more `\book` and `\score` blocks in, order and structure them the way you want to hear your MIDI files, and then, if you’re so inclined, use them in `\include` statements (or don’t) to control which ones are getting compiled.